# Problem with IP Openstack MAAS

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, ip

So i'm using Ubuntu Server 12.04LTS and MAAS with JuJu OpenStack Folsom.
I'm already have one problem with Nova Network. When i using Quantum Gateway in Quotas show me fixed IP -1.
What's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

-1 normally indicates 'unlimited quota'.